# it is possible to freeze a process in linux and restart or shutdown the computer. Then continue with the process that was frozen?

Tags: linux, process, kill

I would like to know if it is possible to freeze a process in Linux and then restart or shut down the computer. And when the computer goes back to work, continue with the process that was frozen.

I tried to use `killall -s STOP` to freeze the process, but when I reboot the computer and use the command `killall -s CONT`, it says no process is located.

Comment: https://criu.org/Main_Page or such might be worth a glance

Comment: @thrig that's definitely worth adding as an answer if you can

Comment: @thrig Add as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot suspend individual processes across a reboot. However, it should be possible to suspend the entire system. When you restart it later the processes that were running may well be able to continue. (Exceptions include those communicating across a network.)

There are two forms of suspend

1. Suspend to memory - this requires continuous power (battery, etc.) but the system is essentially paused.
2. Suspend to disk - this does not require power, but the system will take a little longer to restart. In the Windows world this used to be called Hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

Processes on Linux can (with caveats and limitations) be suspended on Linux; as of 2017 such checkpoint/restore functionality is provided by the CRIU project:

https://criu.org/

Specific limitations include the need to use the same PID, that libraries must be the exact same version before and after a restart, and so forth:

https://criu.org/What_cannot_be_checkpointed

Comment: “need to use the same PID” — meaning in practice you have to run the processes on their own in a PID namespace, because otherwise there's no way to control what PIDs are assigned?